# Can I send a cookie from my server which can be accessed by a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a project where my browser extension makes AJAX calls to my server.
I can sign into the server with several different FQDN domain names
for example

```
https://myserverLANHostname/script_to_call
https://LANipAddress/script_to_call
https://www.example.io/script_to_call
```

My LAMP server generates a different session id for each domain, and the sign in credentials are associated with the session id. The web pages are protected such that a user must be signed in for them to run the php scripts.

So a user signed into one domain name cannot access the server by addressing another domain. For instance if the server LAN address is https://localName they cannot access pages on https://internet_domain_name.io without signing in again.

The browser extension must send AJAX calls to the correct domain, ie the one the user is signed into.  The question is how could my extension achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a server-side script which does not require a signed in user, it returns a JSON string which returns whether the user is signed in on that domain name.

The background.js in the browser extension sends a string of AJAX calls to the script at each domain name using chained promises.  The results show which domain is signed into or that no domain is signed into.

Server side:

```
session_start();
$signedIn = "";
$json_array ="";

//determine value of signedIn from session
(isset($_SESSION['serverUser'])) ? 
    $signedIn = 1: 
    $signedIn = 0;

$json_array = "{\"signedIn\":$signedIn}"; 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_array;
```

Browser extension:

```
function init() {
  fetch(url1)
  .then(processJSONtoObj)
  .then(function(dataObject) {
      //test if user signed
      if(dataObject.signedIn) {
        //user signed into domain 1

      } else {
         return fetch(url2)
      }
  })
  .then(processJSONtoObj)
  .then(function(dataObj2) {
      //test if user signed
      if(dataObject2.signedIn) {
        //user signed into domain 2

      } else {
         //user is not signed into either
      }
  })
}
init();
```